# Python function User

Tags: python, function

I need to create a function that uses `os.urandom(32).hex()`

The function must have:

1. Password Chosen By User
2. Salt (in SHA256)

I am new to python and I am trying the following:

```py
import hashlib, uuid
def salted_password():
    username = input("Enter The Username: ")
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(username + salt).hexdigest()
```

And the truth is that it doesn't work for me.

Could you help me, please.

Comment: May I respectfully point out that `uuid4` does *not* use `os.urandom(32)`?  As copied from `uuid` source code, `uuid4` is: `UUID(bytes=os.urandom(16), version=4)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent your code correctly and add `return` statement (otherwise you would always end with `None`) and convert `str` to `bytes` before feeding into `hashlib.sha256` function, for example using `utf-8` encoding i.e.:

```
import hashlib, uuid
def salted_password():
    username = input("Enter The Username: ")
    salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
    encoded = (username + salt).encode("utf-8")
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(encoded).hexdigest()
    return hashed_password
```

Comment: When I try to do it this way I get: salted_password() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given